# Show/hide menu based on scroll position

Tags: jquery

I added a sticky menu (*.component*) to the footer of my website. It appears if I scroll down 200px from the top of the page, and disappears if less than 200px.

This is basically the idea. However, when it disappears upon scrolling up, it never shows again if I scroll down.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {

  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
    //add effect / animation 
    $('.component').delay(100).animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() == 0) {
      $('.component').hide();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body{ height:1000px; }
.component { position:fixed; }
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="component">
  <!-- Start Nav Structure -->
  <button class="cn-button" id="cn-button">+</button>
  <div class="cn-wrapper" id="cn-wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-briefcase"></span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-headphones"></span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-home"></span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-facetime-video"></span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Thank!

Comment: I changed your code a little to actually show the problem. If you think that was inappropriate, feel free to change it back.

Answer (score 0):

Once hidden, it will not re-appear if you set opacity to 1. You need to call show()

Comment: FYI if you have additional information for your answer, you should [edit it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28547274/edit), not post as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

`hide()` changes `display` property instead of `opacity`, you have to use `animate()` in both cases.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {

  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
    //add effect / animation 
    $('.component').stop(true).animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() == 0) {
      $('.component').stop(true).animate({
        opacity: 0
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.component {
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="component">
  <!-- Start Nav Structure -->
  <button class="cn-button" id="cn-button">+</button>
  <div class="cn-wrapper" id="cn-wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-briefcase"></span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-headphones"></span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-home"></span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-facetime-video"></span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
<div style="height: 800px;"></div>
```

Comment: I changed opacity:0 to display:none and it's working now. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

The scrollTop() method sets or returns the vertical scrollbar position for the selected elements.

Based on your code,if the vertical scrollbar position is less than 200, then it hides the element with class 'component'.

Once hidden based on the example,there will not be any visible content and if there is not content, then 
$(window).scroll(function() {}); will not be executed.That's why the element is not shown when you scroll up once the element is hidden

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        console.log(scroll);
        if (scroll > 200) {
            $('.component').delay(100).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1000).show();
        }
        else {
            $('.component').hide();
        }
    });
```

Below is the fiddle link you can look into for this:
https://jsfiddle.net/ugg15sdL/19/